# Is there a way to create datasets in AuzureML Studio from a tabular model or PowerBi datasets?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

My goal is to import data from a Tabular Model (via MDX or DAX) or PowerBi dataset into AzureML Studio to work with.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to connect to it.

Another alternative would be to establish a connection with pyadomd (https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/). However, I am having problems installing it here as well: ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet.

Has anyone already had experience with this or is there a different approach I'm just not aware of?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Python are you using?

Pyadomd does not currently support python 3.9, due to the pythonnet dependency.

It should work perfectly with python 3.8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working with Python 3.8.